# not allowing space for node label text GOJS

Tags: gojs

I am getting a problem for entering space for text in the label of a node. It is not allowing me to enter the space while creating a new tree. if i edit the label of an already added tree node in the database it is allowing me to enter the space. kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in your situation is have the initial string for new nodes be something visible, such as "(unknown)" or "[enter name]" or whatever is appropriate to your app.

That also helps people realize that there is some text that they can enter and why they should edit it.

Another solution, if the new nodes appear one at a time, would be to automatically start the TextEditingTool on the TextBlock that you want the user to fill out.  This is demonstrated by the http://gojs.net/latest/samples/macros.html sample.  The text editor starts in a "pending delete" mode because all of the existing text is automatically selected, so the user just needs to start typing in order to replace what was there.